# Нахождение объекта в поле зрения OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Надо найти находится ли объект в поле зрения. Для этого можно его вписать в сферу и остаётся только узнать видна ли сфера.

```
glm::mat4 model;
glm::mat4 view;
glm::mat4 projection;
view=glm::lookAt(pos, look+pos, up);
projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)WIDTH / (GLfloat)HEIGHT, 0.05f, 1000.0f);
```

И в шейдере:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Модель отвечает за сдвижение, растягивание, поворот, и т.д. Если не трогать её - выходит как будто её нет.

Надо определить видна ли сфера(и как можно быстрее сделать это). 
Проверить точку на попадание вроде можно просто выполнив перемножение заместо шейдера и посмотреть x,y,z влезли ли в экран. Но со сферой то что делать?

Comment: Сделайте переход в сферические координаты. Радиусом можно взять расстояние до предмета (По теореме Пифагора в R^3).В сферических координатах задайте интервал по вашей камере и проверяйте лежит ли объект в этом интервале.

Comment: @uber42 несколько необычное решение.. есть сомнения в его работоспособности/точности, развернете в ответ? Можно и чуть иначе, и даже без OpenGL. Получите фрустум камеры (пирамида видимости) и проверьте попадание сферы во фрустум (формула легко ищется). Все это делается до отсылки в рендер, на CPU.

Comment: Ну то что еще до отсылки это и так понятно. Сферические координаты это хорошее решение но вот проблема: вектор верха камеры не (1, 0, 0) а (x,y,z) тоесть куда угодно. В glm есть матрицы поворота но это очень долго и муторно(если кто-то сможет написать как это сделать то норм). Насчёт фрустума: нет у меня координат его только матрицы 3 есть и вектора(ещё углы камеры есть).

Comment: @uber42 отсечение по дальности и приближении меня не слишком волнует(да и видимость камеры это многоугольник) если брать по пифагору то полусфера будет.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков причём здесь отсечение по дальности это нужно лишь для вычисления координат, просто видимо вы не слишком хорошо понимайте как с этим работать, реализация наипростейшая.

Comment: Для перехода  в сферические координаты нужно вычислить 2 угла и расстояние углы через atan. И еслибы я понимал как то сделал бы.

Comment: @uber42 Работать может и будет, но вот постоянно считать тригонометрические функции - выглядит неэкономно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat зачем его считать каждый раз, вам достаточно единожды вычислить. Дальше просто смотреть лежит ли объект между координатами вычисленными из этих уголов и расстояния до объекта. Нужно каждый раз вычислять только расстояние, корень из суммы трёх квадратов.

Comment: @uber42 Теперь понял о чем вы. Не совсем понятно, где тут переход в сферические координаты... Еще, по идее корень считать не обязательно, хватит и квадрата расстояния.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, если не будем брать корень ничего не изменится, просто расстояние с запасом получится